# Automatically load Wordpress page on server every XX hours

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a page in my Wordpress site that calculates post popularity and updates several meta fields on the posts and calls a few functions as well.  This page is set to "Private" so that only myself and other admins can see it.  Is there a way to load this page automatically every 6, 12, or 24 hours?

I'd be satisfied with a plugin, but generally prefer to write my own PHP code.

Comment: Do you know http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I did not know about it.  Sorry, I'm new.  I'll repost over there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [cron job](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) or use WordPress directly with [`wp_schedule_event()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event). The latter would probably allow you to remove the placeholder page.